# Carriage return in String Tokenizer in Java

Tags: carriage-return, stringtokenizer

If I only specify carriage return (\r) in the String Tokenizer like this:

StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(line,"\r");

where 'line' is the input string.

When I provide the following text as input:

Hello

Bello

Cello

ie. with two carriage return. (I press 'Enter'after Hello and Bello.)

But the output of this is 3 in System.out.println(st1.countTokens());

Is there an explanation?

Comment: it does look like 3 lines to me.

Comment: But then I pressed enter only after Hello and Bello. After Cello I didn't move the cursor any further till I saved it.

Comment: you have `a,b,c` you split on `,`. The tokens are `a`, `b`, and `c`. As you will note, there is no separator at the beginning of the input either.

Comment: I would recommend that you read the implementation of `StringTokenizer`, it will help you understand how it works in details.

Comment: Oh okay. So in my program carriage return acts as a separator and of course two of them separate three strings. Thank you @njzk2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you split a string using a separator, then, provided that your separator occurs n times, the number of elements after the split will be n+1. Look at this visual example, using comma as separator:

text1,text2,text3,text4

It will yield 4 results

Look at another example:

text1,text2,text3,

It will yield 4 results as well, the last being an empty string.

Comment: Thank you @Lajos Arpad. Took a moment to strike.